# C#: How do you add a destructor to a custom made class?

Tags: c#

How do you add a destructor to a custom made class made in C# so as to destroy it when it's not needed anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(VS.71).aspx).

But you might consider implementing IDisposable which usually offers a more elegant solution. Go [here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a destructor.
Use Dispose() and Finalize() instead.

This is a quite good article on this subject: [When and How to Use Dispose and Finalize in C#](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167)

Comment: Last I checked, finalize used destructor syntax in C#. They're the same thing. (But it'd probably be less confusing to call it a finalizer since a destructor (in C++ at least) works somewhat differently)

Answer (score 1):

Destructors are not used to destroy objects as such, there are used to clean up used resources when your object is destroyed. Destructors are usually used to clean up any unmanaged resources such as when using Interop / p/invoke.

```
class Person
{
    // Destructor
    ~Person()
    {
        // Cleanup resources that the object used here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be really careful!!! You should try and avoid the use of destructors in C# as much as possible.

When your code is:

```
class Person
{
    // Destructor
    ~Person()
    {
        // Clean-up resources that the object used here.
    }
}
```

the compiler is generating this code for you:

```
class Person
{
    // Destructor
    public override void Finalize()
    {
        // your clean up
        base.Finalize();

    }
}
```

As you can see you are just implementing the Finalize method. In the .Net platform a bad implementation of the Finalize method can make your application to have a memory leak and if correctly implemented, and object with a Finalize method implementation takes 2 GC calls to be released.

If you are coming from C++ you should just forget about the idea of a destructor at all, you do not need them the GC should take care of you normal classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
class Car
{
    ~Car()  // destructor
    {
        // cleanup statements...
    }
}
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx).

Comment: This is not a destructor - it's a finalizer. While a C++ destructor and a C# finalizer look similar, the semantics are quite different and they shouldn't be confused.

Answer (score 0):

~className() {}